# Undoing a merge that was pushed to origin

Tags: git

I have just merged my dev branch into my master branch and pushed to origin.  However I need undo that merge completely as if I had never performed the merge in the first place.

What I need back is the state of the master branch as it was before the merge.  I will merge the dev branch back in at a later date.

How should I do this?

Comment: This has been described hundreds of times. Have you searched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git reset --hard` back to the commit before merge. For example, if the merge is at the HEAD of master, do `git reset --hard HEAD~`. Then force-push the branch to origin: `git push origin +master`. Notify everyone who shares the repo about forced push.

Comment: not sure why this answer was voted down. Approach seems to be right.